# Почему мой ответ неверный

Tags: python, python-3.x

Автомат обрабатывает натуральное число N > 1 по следующему алгоритму:

1. Строится двоичная запись числа N.
2. В конец записи (справа) дописывается вторая справа цифра двоичной записи.
3. В конец записи (справа) дописывается вторая слева цифра двоичной записи.
4. Результат переводится в десятичную систему.
   Для скольких значений N в результате работы алгоритма получится число, принадлежащее отрезку [150; 250]?

Мой код:

```
def perevod(n):
    return (int(n,base=2))
s=0
for i in range(10,1000):
    a=bin(i)
    if str(a)[3]==1:
        a=str(a)+'1'
    else:
        a=str(a)+'0'
    if str(a)[-3]==1:
        a=str(a)+'1'
    else:
        a=str(a)+'0'
    b = str(a)[2:]
    c = perevod(b)
    if c>=150 and c<=250:
        s+=1
print(s)
```

Но верный ответ - 24, а мне выдаёт 25, откуда берётся лишняя единица?

Answer (score 2):

Условия `str(a)[3]==1` и `str(a)[-3]==1` ложные, из-за строгой типизации, что, например, при сравнении `'1'` и `1` вернет `False`, т.к. это разные типы.

Да и сами этим проверки излишние, т.к. можно взять сами значения из двоичного представления числа, т.к. [bin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) вернет строку

Переписал код:

```
def perevod(n: str) -> int:
    return int(n, base=2)

s = 0
for i in range(10, 1000):
    a = bin(i)[2:]
    a += a[-2]
    a += a[1]

    c = perevod(a)
    if 150 <= c <= 250:
        s += 1
print(s)
# 24
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ну да, но мне не нравится эта конструкция, поэтому редко к ней прибегаю :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, а еще можно было и без условий, но это плохой код: `s += 150 <= perevod(a) <= 250` :D

Comment: `s += <bool>` не люблю. Автоматическое приведение булева к целому порождает много ошибок. Я его из принципа не использую. "Кто на C программировал, тот над приведениями не смеётся".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, булевое сложение хорошо выглядит в конструкциях с `sum`, типа в подсчете символов `sum(c in '123' for c in text)`, в сравнении с `sum(1 for c in text if c in '123')`. Но это, конечно, вкусовщина

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, ага, обновил ответ :)

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в том что условие `str(a)[3]==1` всегда ложно.

`a` - строка. То есть вызов `str` не нужен. Выражение `a[3]` имеет тип строка и состоит из одного символа. Никакой **символ** не может быть равен **числу** один. Условие всегда ложно.

Правим код:

```
if str(a)[3]=='1':
    a=str(a)+'1'
else:
    a=str(a)+'0'
```

Замечаем что его можно переписать:

```
if str(a)[3] == '1':
    a = str(a) + str(a)[3]
else:
    a = str(a) + str(a)[3]
```

Обе части `if` одинаковы. Убираем `if`:

```
a = str(a) + str(a)[3]
```

Упрощаем:

```
a = a + a[3]
```

Ещё упрощаем:

```
a += a[3]
```

Целиком код выглядит так:

```
def perevod(n):
    return int(n, base=2)


s = 0
for i in range(10, 1000):
    a = bin(i)
    a += a[3]
    a += a[-3]
    b = a[2:]
    c = perevod(b)
    if 150 <= c <= 250:
        s += 1
print(s)
```